# Real-time notifications from Azure DevOps

Tags: notifications, azure-devops

I have multiple pipelines in Azure DevOps, which takes a file as an input and transforms it in subsequent pipelines. I can get the filename in the task name of the pipeline. 
Is there a way for a person who doesn't understand Azure DevOps to get real-time notifications about their file, from Azure DevOps?
Tried Microsoft Workflow but there is a delay in the notification of upto 3-4 mins, so it is not very real-time. 
Please do let me know if anyone faced a similar issue.

Edited to add more details:
The pipeline is something like this. A file is an input to Pipeline A, which in turn triggers 4 pipelines. Pipeline A1 and A2 run in parallel. Once A1 is over, A3 runs and then A4. Then B and so on. Finally there is an artifact that is sent to release pipeline, which again triggers a final pipeline. These triggers are all via REST calls as we need the filename passed along till the end. Pipeline A is triggered via a commit, so if a commit has more than 1 file, the one who commits cannot track each file separately, and only gets build notifications from Azure DevOps. We are looking at sending back a notification from the pipeline that can say, File X is currently at Pipeline A3, back to the person who pushed the commit.

Comment: On what channel do you want the notifications?

Comment: Can you share a sample about your defined notification or which template you use in Microsoft Workflow?According to the specific situation you want to receive the notification, we can judge whether the built-in notification of azure Devops is applicable. Because there is no delay in azure devops built-in notification.

Comment: @Behe Looking at Teams or Outlook, preferably.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT The pipeline is something like this. A file is an input to Pipeline A, which in turn triggers 4 pipelines. Pipeline A1, A2 run in parallel. Once A1 is over, A3 runs and then A4. Then B and so on. Finally there is an artifact that is sent to release pipeline, which again triggers a final pipeline. These triggers are all via REST calls as we need the filename passed along till the end. Pipeline A is triggered via a commit, so if a commit has more than 1 file, the one who commits cannot track each file separately, and only gets build notifications.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure, do you want to process a specific file in a specific pipeline? It is better to provide some image information, which will help me better understand your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I had used custom scripts to mail custom emails, but to specifically address the above issue, I used SendGrid Web API, and that helped to pass on parameters and send across custom notifications without the baggage of configuring or depending on SMTP configurations.